# Double values for selected contact android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a List of contacts with check box.When the user checks the check box i have updated my table field selectedValue with value=1 .Now what i want is i wamna get all the contacts in comma seperated way where selectedValue=1.So for that i have written a query.But my result is not desired.

For eg
I have 4 contacts A,B,C,D in a list.Now if user selects A and C from the list and when i fire that query to get the contacs comma seperated,this is what i get

```
A,A,C,C
```

I dont know why 2 values of A and C are comming

Code

```
public StringBuilder getCheckedContact() {
        database = getWritableDatabase();
        StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
        String query = "Select * From " + contactTable + " where " + selectedContact + "=1";
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                values.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(contactName)));

                if (i != c.getCount() - 1) {
                    values.append(",");
                }
            }
        }
        c.close();
        database.close();
        return values;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop loops over the results once, then the `for` loop loops over the results second time. If you select 4 contacts, you'd get 4*4=16 results.

Why did you add the inner `for` loop?

This could be rewritten as follows:

```
public StringBuilder getCheckedContact() {
    database = getWritableDatabase();
    StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
    String query = "Select * From " + contactTable + " where " + selectedContact + "=1";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);      
    boolean firstItem = true;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        if(firstItem)
            firstItem = false;
        else
            values.append(","); 
       values.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(contactName)));            
    }
    c.close();
    database.close();
    return values;
}
```

Comment: den how will i use this if (i != c.getCount() - 1) {
                    values.append(",");

Comment: Sir i tried you method but value at return statement which i am getting is this ""

Comment: and does your database query return any value? if you step through the code, does the `c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(contactName))` return anything?

Comment: then whatever it is returning will get appended to the StringBuilder, what is the problem?